# I have n rational numbers for the number of persons. Will the run time of this algorithm be O(n^3)?

Tags: algorithm

Initially, set all nodes w with 0(w)=0 to be adopters
(All other nodes start out as nonadopters)
Until there is no change in the set of adopters:

```
  For each nonadopter w simultaneously:
    If at least a O(w) fraction of nodes with edges to w are adopters then
       0(w) becomes an adopter
    Endif
  Endfor
```

Output the final set of adopters

Answer (score 0):

As currently written your algorithm's complexity suffers by processing non-adopter nodes multiple times - if you've got a line graph and a node on the end is the only adopter, then on each iteration you're processing on the order of N nodes and you'll have N iterations since you're only turning one non-adopter into an adopter on each iteration.  You can improve this by using a queue of non-adopters (e.g. in Java you could use a [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)) - every time you flip a non-adopter into an adopter you'll enqueue its non-adopter neighbors in the queue.

It's possible that a non-adopter will be enqueued twice if it's a neighbor of two non-adopters who were flipped to being adopters, so you'll need some way to prevent a non-adopter from being added twice.  One way to do this is with a concurrent hash map, e.g. in Java a [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), that contains non-adopters that need to be processed into adopters.  If a node is not in the map, then add it (e.g. using `putIfAbsent` for the Java map), and then add it to the work queue; if it's already in the map then it's already been added to the queue, so don't add it again.  Once a node has been turned into an adopter then it's probably safe to remove it from the map, just be careful of any potential race conditions.

If you don't want/need this to be concurrent then just use a single worker thread and an unsynchronized queue and map - my assumption was that you wanted to process the nodes concurrently based on the use of `simultaneously` in your pseudocode.

Adding nodes to the queue is O(1), and each node can only be added to the queue once thanks to the map, so in the worst case you add all of the nodes to the queue in O(n).  In the worst case each node is connected to every other node, so for each node in the queue you'll need to traverse each node in the graph to see if it's a non-adopter, resulting in an O(n^2) algorithm.